# How to Reload page whenever browser back button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, e-commerce

I have a web application in Asp.Net MVC. It is a eCommerce site. Recently we have delivered a task we have some issues now. 
When you open site in mobile, there will be a link in the bottom `Request Desktop Site`. After click on it we load desktop site, as we have adoptive designs. 
When user press back button, old mobile loaded again. If User refresh browser, the desktop site will be loaded. Mobile site is loaded because page is cached by the browser. 
How could i reload the whole page when back button is pressed. Need some jQuery help.

There is a lot of solution on stack overflow and google, none work properly :(

Comment: Why to down vote, there is no reason to down vote :(

Answer (score -1):

Add it to your page.

```
<body onload="location.reload(true);">
```

**Update**

```
<body onbeforeunload="location.reload(true);">
```

Comment: do you want me to add this to every page or only to master page?

Comment: this tag, keep reloading page each time it get load. Sorry this can not work